# Send data to network with mdot lorawan

Tags: lora

I'm using mdot and I try to send data with at commands
when i write "at+send=lora" it say OK but I did not receive any data in the server or in the node red 
Is it a problem in server or in the mdot ?
thank you

Comment: I configure the mDot with appEUI (at+ni) and appKey (at+nk) and I didn't receive all the data when I write at+send despite being written OK

Comment: Are you using OTAA or ABP and if you are using OTAA: did you join first?